# Cannot put a button in SlickGrid cell

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am trying to put a button in the cells of one of the columns and do something when it's clicked.

For example I add these lines to the SlickGrid example 1 (http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html)

First to the column array I add:

```
    {id: "Report", name: "Report", field: "Report", width: 40, sortable: true, formatter:reportFormatter}
```

then I add:

```
      function reportFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
          return "<input type='button' value='show' id='reportBtn'/>";
      }

      $('#reportBtn').click(function() {
          alert("hello");
      });
```

The buttons appear in the cells but the click event is not being called !
I must be doing something wrong but can't for the life of me figure it out
can anyone help ?
Thanks!

Comment: You could try passing the function as an onclick argument. I think the issue may be in the order of execution, maybe it's trying to assign the click event to a button not yet created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slick.formatters.js

```
...
"btnForm": buttonsFormatter // add Slick.Formatters
..
  function buttonsFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
      return  "<input type='button' value='"+value+"' id='btnForm' value2='"+row+"' value3='"+cell+"' onClick='fnBtnClick(this);'/>";
  }
```

add your html Script

```
function fnBtnClick( objBtn ){
 alert( "row::[" + objBtn.value2 + "]\n\ncell::[" + objBtn.value3 + "]" );      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use the grid events not button event like below ,

1. will call the onclick event of the grid ,
2. check if the clicked field is your button one
3. do your action

   ```
   grid.onClick.subscribe(function (e, args) {
     //check if your button was clicked  
     if ($(e.target).hasClass("btn")) {
           var item = dataView.getItem(args.row);
           ///do your action
       }

   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the precompiled template slick grid example. Add the property eg. ImageTrial, and in the data structure fill the property with the dynamic input button.

```
<script type=" " id="testtemplate">
<div class="test">
    <b><%=ImageTrial%></b>
     <b><%=ImageTrial2%></b>
</div>
```

```
dataForCell["ImageTrial"] = "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"alert('a " + 1 + "')\">s</button>";

dataForCell["ImageTrial2"] = "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"alert('b " + 2 + "')\">b</button>";
```

Good Luck